# Fastest direction in circular trajectory

Tags: geometry, physics

I have a point P and a vector V. This point is describing a uniform circular trajectory with linear velocity lv and angular velocity av. This trajectory passes through a point P', how do I find out if I would reach P' faster if I went backwards (-V) instead of forward?

Comment: So you want to know if it is nearer going forward or backward? If the angle from actual point to destination is less than half a turn ($\pi$), that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more precise what you mean by linear velocity and angular velocity?
If I get your question right, you have to check whether the inner product $\langle P'-P,V \rangle$ is positive. If this is the case, you move in the "right" direction with $V$ and reach $P'$ faster with $V$ than with $-V$.

Comment: Linear velocity would be the speed of the object, with the direction V. Angular velocity is the angular velocity of the uniform circular motion.